# How can I check isFile() or isDirectory() Function in Java in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, android, ubuntu

In ubuntu, `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` don't work perfectly. I used this code to find out if something is a file or directory:

```
boolean fileName= file.getName().lastIndexOf('.') == -1;
```

But the problem is that I made a folder named `bhargav.panchal`. With the above function, this folder is considered as a file, not a folder.

```
File file=new File("/home/asd/My_Shared_File/bhargav.panchal");

if(file.exists()){
    if(!file.isDirectory()) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "This is File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "This is Directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "File or Directory doesn't exist.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In this condition, the `isDirectory()` and `isFile()` methods always return false.

Comment: You are running this on an Android emulator on an Ubuntu desktop, right? The emulator has its own file system, it does not see the file system of your Ubuntu desktop, so your Android app will not see **/home/volansys11/My_Shared_File/bhargav.panchal** at all.

Comment: isFile() and isDirectory() work correctly on Ubuntu. The error must be in your code. Check that your JVM can access the directory `/home/volansys11/My_Shared_File/`.

Comment: What evidence do you have that `isFile()` or `isDirectory()` are not working perfectly?  It is perfectly correct for `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` to both return false when the file does not exist or is not accessible to the app for other reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are wrong somewhere. On the contrary you cant access external environment with DVM.

reason : it is not possible for applications to interfere with each other based on the OS level
security and Dalvik VMs are confined to a single OS process, *Dalvik itself is not concerned with
runtime security*. Although Dalvik is not relied upon for security, it is interesting to note that most
of the standard Java security classes remain in the Android distribution. These include the
java.lang.SecurityManager and some of the classes in the java.security package. In standard Java
environments, the SecurityManger plays the role analogous to the OS process-level security in
Android. **The SecurityManager typically controls access to resources external to the JVM such as
files, processes, and the network**. In the Android distribution, the standard security framework is
apparently present for applications to use within their `own application space` but is *neither fully
implemented nor configured (no java.policy files are present) for interprocess security.*

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
       if(file.isDirectory()){
           Toast.makeText(activity, "This is File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    
       } else {
           Toast.makeText(activity, "This is Directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

on this

```
        if(!file.isDirectory()){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "This is File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "This is Directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Which conditional is returning false? The one where you check if it exists, or the one where you check if it's a directory?

Comment: use this fuction in ubuntu or linux operating system.