# java.io.ioexception.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(). environment and working directory null error in android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

```
File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard");
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%4d.png video.mp4", null, dir);
```

when i try this line in android,i get environment and working directory null error in android. But when i try that line in java,it worked perfectly.but in android,it has some problem.

Comment: You can't access any directory outside Android source. [Reason see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073553/how-can-i-check-isfile-or-isdirectory-function-in-java-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @hotveryspicy The word 'source' does not appear in that link. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP What I saw earlier, OP asking about using resource of PC( ie. C:\,D:\ ) so I mean that you aren't able to access external resource.

Answer (score 3):

```
i get environment and working directory null
```

It will return null because there is not path like `/mmt/sdcard` instead use `/mnt/sdcard`.

[image]

It will be best if you use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: /sdcard is a synonym to /mnt/sdcard, but you are right that it is strongly recommended to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). But the problem is not with this.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no drive like   **E:** in your either **Emulator** or **Device**.

You can't access any drives of your PC in android like this.

**EDIT :**

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory();
File f = new File(dir."Yourfilename.png");
```

Comment: ok when i put the line as directory File dir = new File("/mmt/sdcard"); it will produced the environment null error in android.is there any environment,to use ffmpeg commandline...

Answer (score 1):

Android security does not allow launching executables from sdcard or usb memory.

You can deploy the executable in your app **files/** directory or in globally writeable **/data/local/** directory. Don't forget to `chmod 777`!

Instead of usung `exec("cmd", env, new File("dir"))` call **exec("dir/cmd")**

Answer (score 0):

Android probably doesn't have an E drive, in fact I can guarantee it.  Android has a linux operating system and doesn't use the same drive naming convention.  Also, I would consider using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) whenever writing code that spawns processes.  It has an easier time parsing command line options.

Comment: ok when i change the directory  as File dir = new File("/mmt/sdcard"); it will produced the environment null error in android.is there any environment,to use ffmpeg commandline?how to set environment in android?